# detecting native objects with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am working with a reflection based object translator.

it basically loops through properties of an object, and assigns the values to properties with the same name/type on the translated object.

**ObjectA.Name = "Joe"**

translates to:

**ObjectB.Name = "Joe"**

I need to put a special case, for when a property is a custom class such as:

**ObjectA.Address**

i was hoping i could detect such properties with IsClass flag of PropertyType

```
propInfo.PropertyType.IsClass
```

but this flag also appears to return true for string properties.

is there another way i could verify that the property is of a non native type?

Comment: String is not a value type either -- it *is* a class.  If you are trying to determine which properties contain *mutable* objects, good luck with that... (Also, how do you define "native" type?)

Comment: The question makes little sense unless "native type" == "reference type".

Comment: The word "native" needs to be removed from the question/title.  It's confusing.  When I read 'native', I think of WIN32 constructs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to determine if the target type is not a primative.  You can probably use `TypeCode` for that, for instance:

```
public bool IsNotCoreType(Type type)
{
    return (type != typeof(object) && Type.GetTypeCode(type) == TypeCode.Object);
}
```

Any non-primitive should return `TypeCode.Object` as the result of `Type.GetTypeCode`, so we can check that we get that and that the type itself is not `System.Object`.

Perhaps that would help?

**UPDATE**: I've renamed the method to *IsNotCoreType* to cover both primitives and non-primitives such as `String`, `DateTime`, etc. (see comments below).

Comment: Why not just use `type.IsPrimitive`?

Comment: ^ Because he'd still need to deal with `System.String`

Comment: @Matthew: I see.  But note that string **is not** a primitive type.  (And incidentally, neither is object.)  So your method name is very misleading.

Comment: @cdhowie: Good point :P, **IsNotPrimitiveOrString** perhaps ;) I'd likey change it to something like **IsNotCoreType** or something similar

Comment: There are other non-primitives with their own dedicated `TypeCode` too: `Decimal`, `DateTime`, and `DBNull` (as far as I can recall).

Comment: Hmm, `GetType` on a `Nullable<T>` returns the underlying `Type`. So `typeof(int?)` != `myNullableInt.GetType()`, as the underlying type for an initialised nullable is the type itself, e.g. `Int32`. Any method calls on an uninitialised `Nullable<T>` will result in an exception.  This might be tricker to solve...

Answer (score 1):

string is an exception, the only primitive type in .NET which is a reference type. You have to consider this exception in your code so that you check if `IsClass` is true and type is not the same as `System.String`.

Comment: String is not a primitive type.  `csharp> typeof(string).IsPrimitive;` -> `false`