# Change Content Attribute

Tags: c#, attributes, data-annotations

I'd like to create an attribute to change the content of the property.

```
[CleanContent]
public string address {get;set;}

address = "hello world   ";
address would change to "hello world"
```

I've used ValidationAttribute, anyone know if I can get Attributes can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes aren't "active" - they are just metadata, and don't do anything unless some calling framework checks for them via reflection and then deliberately does something like invoking a method on them. So no, you can't do this.

Caveat: IL-rewriting tools like post-sharp also use attributes, but they behave in a very different way (by using the attributes to help it re-write the IL after compilation).

Answer (score 0):

You could use attributes to mark what properties you want to clean, but they won't clean it themselves, you need something to call them.

Below is a question closely related to what you are asking, and it provides a few ideas:

[Trim all string properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726714/trim-all-string-properties)