# How to trim class members?

Tags: c#, trim

I have 2 classes like:

```
class customer
{
  string name;
  string address;
  string phone;
}

class company
{
  string name;
  string taxID;
}
```

If I would like to trim the every class member with 1 method, how to do on this way?

for example:

```
customer.name = "AAA   "
customer.address = "city1   "
customer.phone = "   999   "
```

I want to remove the space, like:

```
customer.name = "AAA"
customer.address = "city1"
customer.phone = "999"
```

Comment: what do you mean by trim class member ?

Comment: Rohit, I want to trim(remove space) of each member in both classes.

for example, 

  customer.name = "AAA  ";
  customer.address = "city1   ";
  customer.phone = " 999 ";

I want to update data to

  customer.name = "AAA";
  customer.address = "city1";
  customer.phone = "999";

Comment: @TzungMinWu put your example in the question, to be more clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trim all string properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726714/trim-all-string-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static class StringHelper
{
    /// <summary>Trim all String properties of the given object</summary>
    public static TSelf TrimStringProperties<TSelf>(this TSelf input)
    {
        if (input == null)
            return input;

        var stringProperties = typeof(TSelf).GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));

        foreach (var stringProperty in stringProperties)
        {
            string currentValue = (string)stringProperty.GetValue(input, null);
            if (currentValue != null)
                stringProperty.SetValue(input, currentValue.Trim(), null);
        }
        return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I also found this solution in stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7726831/125032

Comment: You should replace `var stringProperties = input.GetType()...` with `var stringProperties = typeof(TSelf)...`. Also you should check for nullity to fail fast.

Answer (score 4):

Use properties like this :

```
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get 
            {
                return name; 
            }
            set 
            {
                if (value != null)
                    name = value.Trim();
                else
                    name = null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a helper method within your class and apply it in every property setter:

```
private static string Trim(string value)
{
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
           ? String.Empty
           : value.Trim();
}

private string _Name;

public string Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set { _Name = Trim(value); }
}
```