# Using reflection to trim all strings on an object

Tags: c#, reflection, whitespace, trim

Say I have a simple model structure like below and I want to trim the whitespace off of each string in the nested model (`Request` which contains a `Friend`)

```
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }
    public Friend friend { get; set; }
    public string greeting { get; set; }
    public string favoriteFruit { get; set; }
}
```

This implementation only handles the strings on the top `Request` level - I need to be able to handle the `Friend` level (nested) strings as well.

```
private static T TrimWhiteSpaceOnRequest<T>(T obj)
    {
        if (obj != null) 
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = obj!.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties) {
                try
                {
                    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string)) 
                    {
                        var o = property.GetValue(obj, null) ?? "";
                        string s = (string)o;
                        property.SetValue(obj, s.Trim());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //handle nested Friend object here
                        
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    log.info("Error converting field " + field.getName());
                }
            }
            
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

What can I put in the else to reach the nested layer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trim all string properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726714/trim-all-string-properties)

Comment: @zaggler no, that is the answer i drew my inspiration for this solution from.

Comment: @zaggler isn't the suggested duplicate what the OP already has?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay thank, my bad

Comment: @GuruStron somewhat, other answers in that post include recursive calls for `IEnumerable`...

Comment: Check for the type Friend inside your foreach. Then loop through the properties and check for strings if it's a Friend type.

Comment: This works only if you have everything under control. You might break things when you derive from classes that have their own string properties you don't want to touch. So if you have everything under control as a prerequisite why not just trim in the setter?

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively call `TrimWhiteSpaceOnRequest` on the value of non-string properties:

```
else
{
    TrimWhiteSpaceOnRequest(property.GetValue(obj));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call your `TrimWhiteSpaceOnRequest` function on the value of any property that isn't a `string`.

```
if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string)
{
    // Your existing code...
}
else
{
    TrimWhiteSpaceOnRequest(property.GetValue(obj));
}
```

However, that won't get you all the way there. You also need to deal with properties that are collections, like `IEnumerable`. For example, what if instead of a single `Friend` instance `Request` could have multiple `Friend` instances?

You could handle that by checking to see if `obj` can be cast to `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, iterating through it if it can and calling `TrimWhiteSpaceOnRequest` on each instance in the `IEnumerable`.

```
public static void TrimWhiteSpaceOnRequest<T>(this T obj)
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        System.Collections.IEnumerable objAsEnumerable = obj as System.Collections.IEnumerable;
        if (objAsEnumerable != null)
        {
            foreach (object enumerableObj in objAsEnumerable)
            {
                if (enumerableObj != null)
                {
                    TrimStringProperties(enumerableObj);
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        // The rest of your code...
    }
}
```

However, that **still** isn't going to get you there. You also need to handle mutable collections of `string`, for example your `Request.tags` property.

One approach to handling that would be to see if `obj` can be cast to a `System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>`. If it can, iterate through it via a `for` loop and trim each non-null string.

```
public static void TrimWhiteSpaceOnRequest<T>(this T obj)
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.IList<string> objAsList = obj as System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>;
        if (objAsList != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objAsList.Count; i++)
            {
                string listObject = objAsList[i];
                if (listObject != null)
                {
                    objAsList[i] = listObject.Trim();
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        // Check if obj is IEnumerable...
        // The rest of your code...
    }
}
```

This should handle your `Request` `class` as you've presented it. But, you're likely to encounter cases that aren't covered here as you add to that `class`, or if you try to use `TrimWhiteSpaceOnRequest` on other classes.