# how to get reference from property info in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection, recursion

I need to recursively go through all properties in my class and if the property happens to be a string I need to do some custom logic. Please advise what I need to put at the line of recursion.

```
void ProcessAllStrings<T>(ref T objToRip)
{
    BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    Type typeParameterType = typeof (T);

    foreach (PropertyInfo p in typeParameterType.GetProperties(flags))
    {
        Type currentNodeType = p.PropertyType;
        if (currentNodeType == typeof (String))
        {
            //here I do my custom string handling. Code deleted
        }
            //if non primitive and non string then recurse. (nested/inner class instances)
            // see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444908/detecting-native-objects-with-reflection
        else if (currentNodeType != typeof (object) && Type.GetTypeCode(currentNodeType) == TypeCode.Object)
        {
            //I need to get the reference to this property which happens to be a nested class
            //but propertyInfo only provides GetValue(). No GetReference available..
            ProcessAllStrings(ref "dont know what to put here");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using `ref` or generics `T`?  Perhaps your `typeParameterType` should be your input parameter to the method, instead of `objToRip`  EDIT: You might also want to be careful about plausibly running into infinite recursion: if your custom type stores an instance of itself (or somewhere along the property chain does) then you don't want it to keep running over it again and again.

Comment: thx for all replies. very helpful. My requirement is to go thru a whole lot of xml classes generated by xsd.exe and do some custom logic with all string nodes in the xml classes. Hence <T>, since it can be any generic user created class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a reference type then I believe the value *is* a reference.  To recurse just pass the property value back to the function:

```
            else if (currentNodeType != typeof (object) && Type.GetTypeCode(currentNodeType) == TypeCode.Object)
            {
                object propVal = p.GetValue(objToRip,null);

                if(propVal != null) ProcessAllStrings(ref propVal);
            }
```

I would also recommend adding a handler for indexed properties as well.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what I said in the comment and what Mangist has said.  Here's an implementation that also checks for infinite loops on nested type references:

```
private void ProcessAllStrings(Type objectType, HashSet<Type> typesChecked)
{
    if (typesChecked == null)
        typesChecked = new HashSet<Type>();

    if (typesChecked.Contains(objectType))
        return;

    typesChecked.Add(objectType);

    BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

    foreach (PropertyInfo p in objectType.GetProperties(flags))
    {
        Type currentNodeType = p.PropertyType;
        if (currentNodeType == typeof (String))
        {
            //here I do my custom string handling. Code deleted
            Console.WriteLine("Found String Property: " + currentNodeType.FullName + " -> " + p.Name);
        }
            //if non primitive and non string then recurse. (nested/inner class instances)
            // see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444908/detecting-native-objects-with-reflection
        else if (currentNodeType != typeof (object) && Type.GetTypeCode(currentNodeType) == TypeCode.Object)
        {
            //I need to get the reference to this property which happens to be a nested class
            //but propertyInfo only provides GetValue(). No GetReference available..
            ProcessAllStrings(currentNodeType, typesChecked);
        }
    }
}
```

So, say with classes like these, notice that `Foo` has a `Bar` which also points back to `Foo`, so we can test it doesn't infinitely loop:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public Bar Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string BarProp { get; set; }
    public Foo NestedFoo { get; set; }
}
```

You might call it as such:

```
ProcessAllStrings(typeof(Foo), null);
```

Comment: +1. Very nice and robust solution. Appreciate your effort. I don't have any infinite loop situation so I will go with the simpler solution provided by D Dtanley above. thx

Answer (score 0):

Your method wants an object reference, so you'd need to create instances of all those nested classes for the recursion to work.  What you really want is to pass the Type information instead.

Use `Type typeParameterType` as the argument, instead of objToRip.

Then you can call `ProcessAllStrings(currentNodeType );` to do the recursion

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dynamic type instead of a generic type:

```
public static void ProcessAllStrings(dynamic objToRip)
{
    if (objToRip == null) return;
    BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    Type typeParameterType = objToRip.GetType();

    foreach (PropertyInfo p in typeParameterType.GetProperties(flags))
    {
        Type currentNodeType = p.PropertyType;
        if (currentNodeType == typeof(String))
        {
            //here I do my custom string handling. Code deleted
        }
        else if (currentNodeType != typeof(object) && Type.GetTypeCode(currentNodeType) == TypeCode.Object)
        {
            ProcessAllStrings(p.GetValue(objToRip, null));
        }
    }
}
```